# SlingModel still returning null when adapting item

Tags: aem, sling

I am trying to get Sling Models working.

I have a simple annotated POJO that maps to a JCR Node by convention as follows:

```
@Model(adaptables=Resource.class)

public class FlushRule {

@Inject

public String optingRegex;

}
```

I have set a String value in optingRegex.

When I try to use it:

FlushRule currentRule=rule.adaptTo(FlushRule.class);

Although the correct object is in rule, currentRule is null.

I looked in 
`http://localhost:4502/system/console/adapters`
and couldn't find any adapters.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add following lines to the `maven-bundle-plugin` configuration in your `pom.xml`:

```
<configuration>
  <instructions>
    <Sling-Model-Packages>
      org.apache.sling.models.it.models
    </Sling-Model-Packages>
  </instructions>
</configuration>
```

where `org.apache.sling.models.it.models` is the Java package containing your models. The configured package (and all its subpackages) will be scanned for `@Model`s. More information can be found on the [Sling website](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/models.html).

Comment: Thanks. I knew I did something stupid. Unfortunately, I seem to be doing something else stupid as well, as the adapter is not registered and I'm thus still getting a null when I try to adapt. Do you know of  a good approach to debug?

Answer (score 0):

Another reason why the Sling Model object could be null is when the Sling Model has a parameterised constructor and no default constructor.

Example:

```
@Model(adaptables = Resource.class)
public class CompetitionRound {

    @Inject
    String round;

    public CompetitionRound(String round) { 
        this.round = round;
    }

}
```

Add a default constructor and it should work.

```
@Model(adaptables = Resource.class)
public class CompetitionRound {

    @Inject
    String round;

    public CompetitionRound() {

    }   

    public CompetitionRound(String round) { 
        this.round = round;
    }

}
```